Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 19: 'UNIQUE constraint failedl'
I have a C# project with SQLite and Entity Framework. When i try to add new entity to table, there is an error "Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 19: 'UNIQUE constraint failed: Meal.idMeal'".
idMeal in C# class Meal has [Key] and [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] options. In my database idMeal is INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTOINCREMENTED. Adding new elements via EF stopped working after cleaning all elements in database, but if i try to add elements using SQL(
INSERT INTO Meal (Name, Weight, Kcal, Price, CategoryId, CuisineId)
VALUES ('dsds', 100, 100, 100, 1, 1);

), it works, so correct idMeal can be generated. In my opinion there is a problem with EF? How can i solve it?
Meal.cs:
public partial class Meal
    {

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long IdMeal { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
        public double Weight { get; set; }
        public double Kcal { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }

        public long CategoryId { get; set; }
        public long CuisineId { get; set; }

        public virtual Category Category { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual Cuisine Cuisine { get; set; } = null!;
    }

Meal table SQL structure:
CREATE TABLE "Meal" (
    "idMeal"    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "Name"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Weight"    REAL NOT NULL,
    "Kcal"  REAL NOT NULL,
    "Price" REAL NOT NULL,
    "CategoryId"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "CuisineId" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("idMeal" AUTOINCREMENT),
    FOREIGN KEY("CuisineId") REFERENCES "Cuisine"("CuisineId") ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY("CategoryId") REFERENCES "Category"("CategoryId") ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);

Adding element:
using (kursContext db = new kursContext())
{
Meal new_meal = new Meal { Name = name, Weight = weight, Kcal = kcal, Price = price, Category = cat, Cuisine = cuis };
db.Meals.Add(new_meal);
db.SaveChanges();
}

